# Snaphot command in cassandra

Tags: cassandra

A quick question. When we are trying to take snapshot of our keyspace it is throwing an exception as Read Timeout. Below is the command we are using:-

```
./nodetool -h 172.16.100.52  -p 9042 snapshot test;
```

"test"  is our keyspace which has some tables and we were trying to take a backup through the snapshot command. Below is the error we are receiving after a minute :-

> nodetool: Failed to connect to '172.16.100.52:9042' - SocketTimeoutException: 'Read timed out'.

Is there any parameter in the yaml file or env file which you can think of which might help?

Comment: Are you able to launch any other `nodetool` command? `nodetool` is connecting to the node threw JMX. Is 9042 your JMX port? There could also be a network issue, is this command successful : `telnet 172.16.100.52 9042`?

Comment: I am able to Telnet as well as able to run ./nodetool status command.

Comment: Also when I am running the below command :-./nodetool snapshot -t Backup_of_test_KS test . I am able to take snapshot and also able to see the file . Is this command correct ?and can be used?

Answer (score 1):

Try it without specifying your port

```
./nodetool -h 172.16.100.52 snapshot test
```

9042 is the *native binary protocol* port, so that's not going to work.  7199 is the JMX port, which is what nodetool is expecting here.  In fact, you shouldn't *need* to specify that at all.

If you insist on specifying a port, try 7199 (unless you have altered the JMX port).

```
./nodetool -h 172.16.100.52 -p 7199 snapshot test
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue, looks like you are using local JMX connection. Check cassandra-env.sh.

Comment: What changes did you do to solve this ? Some brief explanation please.

Comment: Here is a guide how to configure JMX: https://docs.datastax.com/en/security/6.0/security/secJmxAuth.html